# How to drop all tables in a MySQL database without dropping the database?

Tags: mysql, database

I need to drop all the tables in a database without knowing their names beforehand. The typical procedure is to drop and then recreate the database but this is not an option. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Probably should have asked this beforehand, but better late than never I suppose:  What OS?

Comment: Unix/Linux like OS.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a simpler bash one-liner using mysqldump (from [Thingy Ma Jig Blog](http://www.thingy-ma-jig.co.uk/blog/10-10-2006/mysql-drop-all-tables)).

```
mysqldump -u[USERNAME] -p[PASSWORD] --add-drop-table --no-data [DATABASE] | grep ^DROP | mysql -u[USERNAME] -p[PASSWORD] [DATABASE]
```

If you're getting this error:

```
ERROR 1217 (23000) at line 1: Cannot delete or update a parent row: 
    a foreign key constraint fails
```

Try the following:

```
(echo 'SET foreign_key_checks = 0;'; 
 (mysqldump -u[USERNAME] -p[PASSWORD] --add-drop-table --no-data [DATABASE] | 
     grep ^DROP); 
 echo 'SET foreign_key_checks = 1;') | \
    mysql -u[USERNAME] -p[PASSWORD] -b [DATABASE]
```

Now it ignores the constraints.

Answer (score 4):

You should use the [information_schema](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html) tables to fetch the metadata about the database, and then drop the tables listed there.

Comment: Would be great to have the proper example.

Answer (score 3):

You could try a quick shell script to do it too:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n'
for table in `mysql <databaseName> -N -e 'show tables'`; do
    echo mysql <databaseName> -e "drop table $table"
done
```

Remove `echo` after you've checked that it's going to do what you expect.

Comment: By the way, why do you write '$' before IFS's value? Why doesn't it look like "IFS='\n'" ?

Comment: @o_OTync Using `$''` causes bash to interpret backslashed sequences instead of taking them literally.  `'\n'` would contain exactly \n, just like that, which `$IFS` would understand to be splitting on \ and n characters.  `$'\n'` would contain a newline character, 0x0D.  Take a look here for more info: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI\_002dC-Quoting.

Comment: I think this is simpler than using the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

Answer (score 0):

There was an [entry on the Xaprb blog](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2009/10/29/making-changes-to-many-tables-at-once/) recently which covers this nicely.

It includes why using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` isn't always a good thing and references a tool from those lovely people at [Maatkit](http://www.maatkit.org/).

Try the following with [`mk-find`](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-find.html):

```
mk-find '<database>' --printf 'DROP TABLE %D.%N'
```

If you're happy with the results then:

```
mk-find '<database>' --exec 'DROP TABLE %D.%N'
```

Answer (score -3):

If you have filesystem access, then just `rm -rf databasename/*` :).

The Drop database statement does the same... Excerpt from the MySQL manual:

*The DROP DATABASE statement removes from the given database directory those files and directories that MySQL itself may create during normal operation:*

Comment: Extremely bad idea for any non-trivial setup as MySQL is not expecting these files to suddenly disappear and could be in the middle of any number of operations, transactions, replication, locks...

Comment: Would you consider revising your answer to include the proper commands and procedure then?